# Is it possible to change the constants which are defined in django models.py from admin page?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

```
class Parameters(DateTimeBase):

    SIMPLE = 1
    MEDIUM = 2
    VERY_CUT_UP = 3
    COMPLEXITY_CHOICES = (
        (SIMPLE, 'Simple roof'),
        (MEDIUM, 'Medium difficulty'),
        (VERY_CUT_UP, 'Very cut-up roof'),
    )
   complexity = models.IntegerField(choices=COMPLEXITY_CHOICES, default=SIMPLE)
```

Comment: You can create a different DB model for the constants and reference them as a foreign key. That would be easier for you handle the constants from admin. otherwise its not possible to handle constants from admin directly with the above structure